# Ruby class#method in text, class.method in code snippet

Tags: ruby

I've just learned the difference between Array.push(*more_than_one) vs Array << just_one) but confused by the poster using Class#Method in his *comments* and Class.method in the *code snippet* (link 1 below).

I've read the post about Java # vs . in responses (link 2 below), but didn't catch the relevance to the HTML part.

I'm learning Ruby (before rails) and am from a C# .NetCF background (little lol at the # here) and could really do with some help as to why the notation differs between *comments* and *code snippets* ?

**link 1** [Ruby - Difference between Array#<< and Array#push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569529/ruby-difference-between-array-and-arraypush)

**link 2** [Why do some folks use Class#method instead of Class.method in correspondence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247793/why-do-some-folks-use-classmethod-instead-of-class-method-in-correspondence)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a convention used to distinguish between class/module methods and instance methods when writing about Ruby code.

You'll see `Foo::bar` to denote class/module methods and `Foo#bar` for instance methods.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123445/whats-the-rationale-history-for-the-convention-of-identifying-methods-in-ruby) question and its answers for some insight into the history of the different symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's only a Ruby **Documentation** convention.

`Foo#bar` for class `Foo`'s *instance method* `bar`, and you should call it like `Foo.new.bar` in your code.

`Foo::bar` for class `Foo`'s *class method* `bar`, and you should call it like `Foo.bar` in your code.